# I just shorted my motherboard. Is it doomed?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure

Motherboard: `Gigabyte GA-Z77-D3H`

I screwed it straight in without realizing and it wouldn't start, then I realized and put the extra screws on as I should have done in the first place.

Now everything lights up and it comes on when i turn it on but it bleeps about ten times and restarts without properly booting or anything. I am worried I have fried it but it is just as plausible that I have not plugged something important in as it has been years since I made a setup from scratch.

I took out the ram and it did nothing.

- Processor: `Intel Core i5 3570K 3.4GHz Socket 1155 6MB`
- Ram:  `G-Skill 8GB (2x4GB) DDR3 1600Mhz RipjawsX Memory Kit CL9`
- HDD: `old seagate SATA from another computer`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately the motherboard is likely to be unrecoverable.

Looking up the [beep codes](https://www.google.com/search?q=beep%20codes) seems to indicate that 10 beeps is a CMOS/BIOS error:

> • [CMOS shutdown Read/Write error](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm)
>
> • [Your problem lies deep inside the CMOS. All chips associated with the CMOS will likely have to be replaced. Your best bet is to get a new motherboard.](http://www.pchell.com/hardware/beepcodes.shtml)
>
> • [The shutdown for the CMOS has failed](http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/amibeep.htm)

You *may* be able to try changing the [CMOS battery](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000239.htm) and resetting it, but chances are that the UEFI has burned out.

That board has a [DualBIOS](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4140#sp) feature which you may be able to [use](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4140#manual) to reset the BIOS, but again, chances are the system is too damaged for even that to work.

If the board is still new, you can try exchanging it.

Comment: Would resetting bios do anything when I haven't had a chance to set it?

Comment: @Luke, that's why I said try. I had an EPoX board that died for no reason after the warranty had expired. I contacted them about it and they offered to do a "courtesy repair", but just replaced it outright. Some companies are great and have wonderful public-relations. (Some companies are crap though; like Intel. I bought their QX3 microscope which didn't work. They gave me a "refund" but in the end, I ended with -$75 and no microscope.)

Comment: @Magpie, probably not. I only mentioned the reset because it was linked to by one of the above pages. The problem is that the 10-beep code could also be caused by other BIOS issues, so resetting may work, but by short-circuiting it, you probably burned out the chip itself or one of the other wires or components leading to/from it which could lead to the same error, but much worse (like having a cough can be a symptom of something easy to treat or something untreatable).

Comment: @Synetech I'm the middle man at my job, that's why I hate it... I agree some companies are good (*cough* ASUS *cough*), but others are nightmares

Comment: Just to confirm. Replaced Motherboard and it works fine now.

Comment: Also I think it's fair to go for a refund because ot wasn't on the instructions (I looked second time around you see...) Only that is not the company that sold it to me's fault, more gigabyte. I should probably write to them directly?